# Pandas Conditional Column Count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
a1   |  a2  |  b3  |  b4  |  b5  |  c | d
 1   |   2  |   3  |  4   |   5  |  1 | 1 
 1   |   4  |   5  |  3   |   2  |  0 | 0
 2   |   3  |   1  |  1   |   0  |  0 | 0
```

I want to create two columns, "a_count", and "b_count".

For each row where the value of "d" is 1 OR "c" is 0:

- "a_count" should represent the number of times '1' appears in a1 or
  a2
- "b_count" should represent the number of times '1' appears in
  b3/b4/b5

If both 'd' and 'c' are 0 it should just be a 0.

So the resulting output would look like...

```
a1   |  a2  |  b3  |  b4  |  b5  |  c  |     d     |  a_count  | b_count
 1   |   2  |   3  |  4   |   5  |  0  |     0     |     0     |    0
 1   |   4  |   5  |  3   |   2  |  1  |     0     |     1     |    0
 1   |   1  |   1  |  1   |   0  |  0  |     1     |     2     |    2
```

It's fine if I compute a_count and b_count separately. 
I guess I could use a combination of np.where, etc. but I think what confused me was figuring out how to get a count within either columns a1/a2 or b3/b4/b5 where the respective values were 1 AND the condition for c and d was met.

Maybe it's a straightforward question but my brain is just fried right now :( If it is too trivial can someone just point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `np.where` is a good choice for this problem.

```
df['a_count'] = np.where((df['c'] == 0) & (df['d'] == 0), 0, (df[['a1', 'a2']]==1).sum(1))
df['b_count'] = np.where((df['c'] == 0) & (df['d'] == 0), 0, (df[['b3', 'b4', 'b5']]==1).sum(1))
```

Comment: df['a_count'] = np.where((df['c'] == 0) | (df['d'] == 0), 0, (df[['a1', 'a2']]==1).sum(1)) 
So, I modified it to use an OR between 'c' and 'd' equaling 0. But what does that 0 after (df['d'] == 0) do?
Is this saying if c | d == 0, set count to 1. Else, get sum of a1/a2 where it's equal to 1?

Comment: Yes, `np.where` is a vectorized if/then/else statement. `if x > 1 then print('yes') else print('no')` in np.where form gets translated to `np.where(x>1, print('yes'), print('no'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
anyone = df[['c', 'd']].eq(1).any(1)
df['a_count'] = df.filter(like='a').eq(1).sum(1) * anyone
df['b_count'] = df.filter(like='b').eq(1).sum(1) * anyone

print(df)

   a1  a2  b3  b4  b5  c  d  a_count  b_count
0   1   2   3   4   5  1  1        1        0
1   1   4   5   3   2  0  0        0        0
2   2   3   1   1   0  0  0        0        0
```

---

***with `numpy` getting same results***

```
anyone = (df[['c', 'd']].values == 1).any(1)
df['a_count'] = (df.filter(like='a').values == 1).sum(1) * anyone
df['b_count'] = (df.filter(like='b').values == 1).sum(1) * anyone

print(df)
```