# Pandas Conditional Column Count (complicated mapping)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I previously asked a similar question: [Pandas Conditional Column Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454827/pandas-conditional-column-count/41454901?noredirect=1#comment70117152_41454901)

But modified it as such:

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
a1   |  a2  |  b3  |  b4  |  b5  |  c | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5
 1   |   2  |   3  |  4   |   5  |  1 | 1  | 0  |  0 |  0 | 0
 1   |   4  |   5  |  3   |   2  |  0 | 0  | 1  |  1 |  1 | 0
 2   |   3  |   1  |  1   |   0  |  0 | 0  | 0  |  1 |  0 | 1
```

I want to create two columns, "a_count", and "b_count".

Essentially, the boolean flag in d1-d5 corresponds to a1/a2/b3/b4/b5. i.e. in the first row, for d1 that '1' is corresponding to the entity for the first row under a1.

I can assume that the columns for d1-d5 are going to match up evenly with the columns in a1/a2/b3/b4/b5 (i.e. the total # will be equal, guaranteeing that each of the cols from a or b will have a corresponding 'd' column).

I want to do something similar to my original question, where I have "a_count" and "b_count" columns, but the condition is slightly different. Previously, I just had one column 'd' for everything. Since I've split it up to correspond with specific columns now...

'a' count represents the count of times a column starting with 'a' has **corresponding** 'd' column == 1, while c == 0 for the entire row. So for example:

```
a1   |  a2  |  b3  |  b4  |  b5  |  c | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | a_count | b_count 
 1   |   2  |   3  |  4   |   5  |  1 | 1  | 0  |  0 |  0 | 0  |    0    |   0
 1   |   4  |   5  |  3   |   2  |  0 | 0  | 1  |  1 |  1 | 0  |    1    |   0 
 2   |   3  |   1  |  1   |   0  |  0 | 1  | 1  |  1 |  0 | 1  |    0    |   1
```

I initially thought of using something like this (that a user commented in the original thread):

```
anyone = df[['c', 'd']].eq(1).any(1)
df['a_count'] = df.filter(like='a').eq(1).sum(1) * anyone
df['b_count'] = df.filter(like='b').eq(1).sum(1) * anyone
```

But the problem with that is that I won't be able to guarantee a match between a1/d1, a2/d2, b3/d3, b4/d4, b5/d5 if I just arbitrarily sum them wherever it's equal to 1... (if that makes sense).

My intuition is to use a really convoluted np.where statement (see below). I didn't know if there was a more elegant way to do this, though...

```
df['z1'] = np.where(((df['c'] == 0) & (df['a1'] == 1) & (df['d1'] == 1), 1, 0)
df['z2'] = np.where(((df['c'] == 0) & (df['a2'] == 1) & (df['d2'] == 1), 1, 0)
df['z3'] = np.where(((df['c'] == 0) & (df['b3'] == 1) & (df['d3'] == 1), 1, 0)
df['z4'] = np.where(((df['c'] == 0) & (df['b4'] == 1) & (df['d4'] == 1), 1, 0)
df['z5'] = np.where(((df['c'] == 0) & (df['b5'] == 1) & (df['d5'] == 1), 1, 0)
```

Then,

```
df['a_count'] = df['z1'] + df['z2']
df['b_count'] = df['z3'] + df['z4'] + df['z5']
```

There has got to be a more elegant way of doing this so I don't create useless columns and make my table unnecessarily large...

Comment: I am not sure if understand. Is possible use match by dictionaries like `a = {'a1':'d1','a2':'d2'}` and 
`b = {'b4':'d4','b5':'d5','b3':'d3'}` ?

Comment: To clarify, if c == 0 & a1 == 1 & d1 == 1, then that counts as 1
If in addition to that, c ==0 & a2 == 1 & d2 == 1, then a_count total is 2
But if:
c == 0 & a2 == 1 & d2 == 0, then a_count total is just 1 (from the first value).
Would the dictionary be used to mask over my dataframe?

Comment: But I am a bit confused, because your code does not return `a_count=0,1,2` and `b_count=0,2,2`. Why?

Comment: I updated the sample data, there was a typo. It should be a_count=0,1,0 and b_count = 0,0,1

Comment: The code I had would manually check for each pair (a1/d1, a2/d2, b3/d3, b4/d4, b5/d5) first if c==0, and whether each of the values in the pair == 1. If all of those are satisfied it should set the value in the temporary col to 1. Since I know which columns correspond to individual counts for each type (a or b), I manually added them together to get a_count and b_count. I'm very sure that my approach is idiotic and that this is a trivial problem; I'm just not familiar with pandas to apply the right map or technique for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict` for mapping `a`, `b` columns with `d` first:

```
d = {'a1':'d1','a2':'d2','b4':'d4','b5':'d5','b3':'d3'}
```

Then multiple mask by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) (convert to `int` is neccesary for avoid `warning`) and last [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydattotal_seca.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df1 = (df[list(d.keys())] == 1).mul((df[list(d.values())] == 1).astype(int).values, axis=0)
                               .mul(df.c == 0, axis=0)
print (df1)
   a2  b5  b4  b3  a1
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   1   0

df['a_count'] = df1.filter(like='a').sum(axis=1)
df['b_count'] = df1.filter(like='b').sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   a1  a2  b3  b4  b5  c  d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  a_count  b_count
0   1   2   3   4   5  1   1   0   0   0   0        0        0
1   1   4   5   3   2  0   0   1   1   1   0        0        0
2   2   3   1   1   0  0   0   0   1   0   1        0        1
```

Another more dynamic, but also more complicated solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
#keep original df
df2 = df.copy()
#set index with columns not matches
df = df.set_index('c')
#create Multiindex with ints and strings
a = df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
b = df.columns.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)', expand=False)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a,b])
df.columns = mux
#SORT INDEX FOR ALIGN ab dataframe with d
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   1     2     3     4     5   
   a  d  a  d  b  d  b  d  b  d
c                              
1  1  1  2  0  3  0  4  0  5  0
0  1  0  4  1  5  1  3  1  2  0
0  2  0  3  0  1  1  1  0  0  1
```

```
#select columns with a,b
idx = pd.IndexSlice
ab = df.loc[:, idx[:, ['a','b']]]
print (ab)
   1  2  3  4  5
   a  a  b  b  b
c               
1  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  4  5  3  2
0  2  3  1  1  0

#select columns with d
d = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'd']]
print (d)
   1  2  3  4  5
   d  d  d  d  d
c               
1  1  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1  1  0
0  0  0  1  0  1
```

```
#multiple masks
df1 = (ab == 1).mul((d == 1).astype(int).values, axis=0)
               .mul(df.index == 0, axis=0)
               .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   1  2  3  4  5
   a  a  b  b  b
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0

#select columns with a and b
df2['a_count'] =  df1.loc[:, idx[:, 'a']].sum(axis=1)
df2['b_count'] =  df1.loc[:, idx[:, 'b']].sum(axis=1)
print (df2)
   a1  a2  b3  b4  b5  c  d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  a_count  b_count
0   1   2   3   4   5  1   1   0   0   0   0        0        0
1   1   4   5   3   2  0   0   1   1   1   0        0        0
2   2   3   1   1   0  0   0   0   1   0   1        0        1
```

Comment: Oh very cool; didn't think about using a dictionary in that way!

Comment: Yes, it was hardest problem, but I am glad can help you. Thank you for accepting!